# Layout weight apparently work well, but not in some real devices

Tags: android, android-layout

I have searched and tried a lot of solution without success.

I have a full size image in the main screen of my app. So i want to organize this image with 2 buttons on the bottom of the screen.

With this XML everything seems ok but in some devices (HTC One, LG Nexus 4...) **the image is not visible** . In others devices is all ok and indeed i think the code is pretty good. I know that could be a weight problem but if i use relative layout there is the problem of the overlapping (i don't want use scroll view because the main screen must be all visible immediatly).

What i'm missing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/main_gradient">

<ImageView android:id="@+id/imgMainLogo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image_description"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"/>

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:gravity="bottom">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonRegister"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="@string/main_btn_register"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonEnter"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="@string/main_btn_enter"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Curious: how large is your logo in px for each density?

Comment: Actually. Either way I'd recommend using RelativeLayout. You should add an ID to your button container (the LinearLayout) then move the ImageView below that container in your xml. At that point, add android:layout_above="@id/button_container" to the ImageView and android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" to your button container. That will ensure there is no overlap.

Comment: This could be a trick, i will check all the posted solutions and i will come back as soon as possible :) I have only one image and i have left to Android to scale the size. The image is contained in "hdpi" folder as default.

Comment: Really weird...the RelativeLayout approach seems works well but the image on the topo is still invisible, only in those devices. I'm starting to change the structure of the layout then, if the problem remains, the problem is the image itself.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the weight related changes that I have made. Let me know if it works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_gradient"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgMainLogo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_description"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonRegister"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="@string/main_btn_register"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonEnter"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="@string/main_btn_enter"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is the same approach but i have to check. Maybe i will need some time to come back, thank you!

Comment: I have add some weights in it.

Comment: Just tested. This approach doesn't work, the result is really similar to mine

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Register"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Enter"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```